# website is not opening in mobile device

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

We have design a website using `wordpress` it is working well on desktop that is http://www.jainbakers.com but when I am try to open it in mobile browser then it is redirecting on http://www.google.uk so can you tell me the solutions for this problem.

Comment: what should i do now i am very new in web designing and developing.

Comment: If you have used any index page redirection or htaccess, post your code